# How to do I randomize numbers for some seconds?

Tags: java, random, numbers

In java people can put randomized number:

```
import java.util.Random;
```

I'm developing a game and its essential for the randomizers in my game. But it changes numbers to fast for me and I really liked a time for it to change to a new randomized number. How do I do that? I tried to search on google but gave me nothing.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question, please? I don't understand what do you want.

Comment: I haven't seen google returning "NOTHING"!

Comment: What search keyword you have tried at google? I don't believe it would give you nothing.

Comment: "But it changes numbers to fast for me", do you mean you need some delay time. If so, you can use Thread.sleep().

Answer (score 2):

I think perhaps you've misunderstood how it works. When you call, for example, `random.nextInt(10);` it returns a different number every time you call it. It is not 'always changing', it generates a sequence of numbers, and you are in control of when it does this. It will not generate new numbers until you ask it to.

You can assign it to a variable if you want to save it between calls to `nextInt()`, etc.

Comment: When i do that, it would only do up to 10. And I know that already... I was saying that can it call in a new number maybe for 3 seconds later?

Comment: No. It has no state. You get a new number when you ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

Google gave you nothing?  I highly doubt that.

```
public class Game {
    private Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    // Generate all the random numbers you need.
}
```

If you need them on a schedule, use a `Timer` to only call for the next number when the alarm goes off.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Timer` and `TimerTask` for generating random numbers at regular intervals like this:

```
public class MyRandomNumberGenerator extends TimerTask{
int ramdomNumber =0;
Random r = new Random();
@Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        randomNumber = r.nextInt(10);
        //Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive) here it is 10,

    }
public int getRandomNumber(){
    return randomNumber;
} 

}
```

Now in your main class where you want to use random numbers

use this code

```
MyRandomNumberGenerator rng = new MyRandomNUmberGenerator();
Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(rng,System.getCurrentTimeMillis,10000);
int r = rng.getRandomNumber();
```

Here `System.getCurrentTimeMillis` means start the timer from now and `10000` means that every `10000` millisecond a new Random Number will be created and stored in the instance variable and then you can access that random number using the `getRandomNumber` method of `MyRandomNumberGenerator` class.

Answer (score 0):

The methods that you call on a `Random` object return a new random number each time you call them. If that's not what you want, then write your own class that holds an instance of `Random`, and that checks when the last time was you've called it to get a new random number. If it's time for a new one, return a new one. Something like this:

```
class TimedRandom {
    private final Random random = new Random();

    private int lastNumber;
    private long lastRefreshTime;

    public int getNumber() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // If it's more than 2 seconds ago, generate a new random number
        if (now - lastRefreshTime > 2000L) {
            lastNumber = random.nextInt();
        }

        lastRefreshTime = now;
        return lastNumber;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int number = random.nextInt(10);
        System.out.println("number: " + number);
        // sleep 1s every generation
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    }
}
```